# How to find and parse line in text file starting with certain text?

Tags: python

> (0 grid written by ANSYS Meshing
> nodes:       (10 (id start
> end type) (x y z ...))
> faces:       (13 (id start end type elemType)
> (v-0 v-1 .. v-n right-cell left-cell ...))
> cells:  (12 (id start end type elemtype))
> parent-face: (59 (start end
> parent child) (nchilds child0 child1 ...))
> )
> (2 3)
> (10 (0 1 73cb 0))
> (13 (0 1 e7ba 0))
> (12 (0 1 0 0))

I want to read a .txt file which containing approximately 11 lines.
particularly line number 8 indicates whether given file is  two dimensions or three dimensions. Line number 8 basically starts with (2 and 3 indicates three dimension.
for that purpose I have written following code. My output should be "Dimensions = 3" but I unable to get it. can anyone correct my code? >

```
import os
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
root = os.getcwd()
file = "test.txt"
file_name = os.path.join(root, file)
f = open(file_name)
eof = file_len(file_name)
print(eof)
current_pos = 1
row = f.readline()
dimensions = str(row[8])
while current_pos<=eof:
   if row.startswith("(2"):
      print("Dimensions = " + str(dimensions))
      current_pos+= 1
```

Comment: Better, simpler ways to read from a text file [here](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#iterating-over-each-line-in-the-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

You should use `f.readlines()` with **s** instead of `f.readline()`. The line **8** in the text is defined by **7** because the first line is numbered by **0**.

```
import os
root = os.getcwd()
file = "test.txt"
file_name = os.path.join(root, file)
f = open(file_name)      # Opening the file.
line8 = f.readlines()[7] # Reading line N°_8 from the file.
# If the number '3' is figured in this line then we have '3D' else we have only '2D'
if '3' in line8:          
   dimensions=3
else: 
   dimensions=2
   
print("Dimensions = " + str(dimensions))
```

[**Output**]

```
Dimensions = 3
```

Comment: NO,  My output should be "Dimensions = 3" only not like "Dimensions =(2  3)"

Comment: @Dev, Now the code is Updated. It will be given "**Dimensions = 3**"  when we have **(2 3)**, and will be "**Dimensions = 2**"  when we have only  **(2)**

Comment: can you explain to me how the code works?

Comment: @Dev, firstly we get the 8th line using: **f.readlines()[7]** then we check if the number **3** is there that's mean **3D** else it's will be **2D**

Comment: If we use (2,23) instead of (2,3) the  code got same result like Dimensions = 3 . can you suggest another way for this problem

Comment: In this case, we can match exactly the shape that appears in the input file. i.e: if we have **(2,3)** the condition code will be:  **if line8 == '(2,3)':**